# Change a custom mouse on hover

Tags: jquery, css, hyperlink, hover, cursor

I would like to have a bigger and filled circle on the hover link. (".cursor--canvas") and change the shape of the ".cursor--small" from a circle to a triangle for exemple.

[MY JS FIDDLE HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/L6j307kx/3/)

```
  <!-- The cursor elements --> 
  <div class="cursor cursor--small"></div>
  <canvas class="cursor cursor--canvas" resize></canvas>

  <a class="link" href="#">HELLO ! </a>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/paper.js/0.12.0/paper-core.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably over-complicating things by implementing a cursor with JavaScript yourself when the browser provides a convenient method of doing this via the CSS `cursor` property. If you have an image (inline or separate file) to use as a cursor you can simply use:

```
cursor: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="50" height="50" viewBox="0 0 20 20"><path fill="none" stroke="%23000000" d="M11 10a1 1 0 01-1 1 1 1 0 01-1-1 1 1 0 011-1 1 1 0 011 1zm8 0a9 9 0 01-9 9 9 9 0 01-9-9 9 9 0 019-9 9 9 0 019 9z"/></svg>'), auto;
```

to define a custom cursor for that element.

An example of having different cursors for different elements is shown below:

```css
#back {
    padding: 70px 20px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    cursor: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="50" height="50" viewBox="0 0 20 20"><path fill="none" stroke="%23000000" d="M11 10a1 1 0 01-1 1 1 1 0 01-1-1 1 1 0 011-1 1 1 0 011 1zm8 0a9 9 0 01-9 9 9 9 0 01-9-9 9 9 0 019-9 9 9 0 019 9z"/></svg>') 25 25, auto;
}
h1 {
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: green;
    cursor: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="50" height="50" viewBox="0 0 20 20"><path fill="none" stroke="%23000000" d="M10 2L2 18h16z"/></svg>') 25 25, auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="back">
    <h1>Triangle cursor in here!</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: This is not i'm looking for :) Here's the tutorial i've used for this custom mouse : https://tympanus.net/codrops/2019/01/31/custom-cursor-effects/